# Add two hyperlink in same text box

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have to insert two hyperlinks that must open consecutively in the same textbox in reporting SQL with function "Action" "Go to URL" in the text box proprieties.

it's possible?
if it is possible how should i insert and divide the two links to make them work?

Tanks

SQL Reporting Service - report design view

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure what you mean by "must open consecutively", but one potential solution is to use two placeholders in the textbox -- one for each hyperlink.  Each placeholder can have it's own action.  Another thought would be to set the action for one hyperlink on the actual textbox and another in a single placeholder.  When the report viewer clicks the link, theoretically it should open both links -- however, I haven't tested this theory.